# Error in large iterations of n-dimensional 4th-Order Runge-Kutta solver

Tags: c++, runge-kutta

The code presented here work fine but say to find bifurcation points when varying omega for (-30,30) rather than (10,30), thus changing 'int o' from 2000 to 6000 the following message appears on the screen,

Unhandled exception at at 0x7665B802 in Bifurcation_Plotter.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x012FF544.

The time step needs to stay as is to ensure accuracy of results.

All help greatly appreciated :)

```
//NOTE: this code has memory issues, if compiling be careful to adjust step size to obtain the desired plot
    //This program computes solutions for I_A or I_B and stores them to an array
    //This array is then evaluated to find the local maxima
    //Further evaluation finds what the local maxima settle to
    //These settled values are found for a varying omega to produce a bifurcation plot


    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cmath>

        using namespace std;

        double *CoupledLaser_rhs(double t, int m, double x[]);
        double *rk4vec (double t0, int m, double u0[], double dt, double *f(double t, int m, double x[]));

        //Global parameter values
            double beta = 8.5;
            double gama = 10.0;
            double alpha = 2.0;
            double kappa = 39.97501809;//d=1.2
            double omega;
            double lambda = 2;

        int main()
        {
            //file to store bif points
            string bif_points_filename = "(10,30)mod_bif_points_IA_d=1.2.txt";
            ofstream bif_unit;


            //


            double dt = 0.01;//time-step
            double domega = 0.01;//omega-step
            int i;
            int j;
            int k;
            int l;
            int m = 6;//no. of dimensions
            int n = 5000;//no. of time evaluation steps (n*dt = time)
            int o = 2000;//no. of delta_omega evaluation steps
            double t;
            double *x;
            double *xnew;
            double current;

            //

            cout<<"\n";
            cout<<"CoupledLaser_RKSolver\n";
            cout<<"Compute solutions of the Coupled Laser system.\n";
            cout<<"Write data to file.\n";

            //


            //I.C.'s in 0th entry//
            t = 0.0;
            omega=10;

            x = new double [m];
            x[0] = 1.0;
            x[1] = 1.0;
            x[2] = 1.0;
            x[3] = 1.0;
            x[4] = 0.001;
            x[5] = 0.001;


            //


            //define array to store elements of I_A
            double *arr = new double[1000];

        //


        //Approximate solution at equally spaced times of time step dt//
        bif_unit.open(bif_points_filename.c_str());
        for(l=0; l<o; l++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<n-1000; j++)
                {
                    current = ((x[0])*(x[0])+(x[1])*(x[1]));
                    xnew = rk4vec(t, m, x, dt, CoupledLaser_rhs);
                    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
                    {
                        x[i] = xnew[i];
                    }
                    t=t+dt;
                }   
            arr[0]=current;
            for(j=0; j<1000; j++)
                {
                    arr[j]=((x[0])*(x[0])+(x[1])*(x[1]));
                    xnew = rk4vec(t, m, x, dt, CoupledLaser_rhs);
                    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
                    {
                        x[i] = xnew[i];
                    }
                    t=t+dt;
                }
            for(k=50; k<1000-50; k++)
                {
                    if(arr[k]>arr[k+1] && arr[k]>arr[k-1])
                        {
                            bif_unit <<omega<<","<< arr[k]<<"\n";
                        }
                }
            omega = omega + domega;
        }

        bif_unit.close();

        //

    cout << "Created local maxima vs omega bifurcation file " << bif_points_filename<<"\".\n";



        //END//

        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"CoupledLaser_ODE:\n";
        cout<<"Normal end of execution.\n";
        cout<<"\n";
    }

//

//Evaluates the rhs of the coupled laser field equations
//t; value of the independent time variable, m; spatial dimension, x[]; values of the dependent variables at time t
//Output; values of the derivatives of the dependent variables at time t
//x[0] = E_Ax, x[1] = E_Ay, x[2] = E_Bx, x[3] = E_By, x[4] = N_A, x[5] = N_B

double *CoupledLaser_rhs(double t, int m, double x[])
{
    double *dxdt;
    dxdt = new double [m];

    dxdt[0] = beta*gama*(x[4]*x[0]) + alpha*beta*gama*(x[4]*x[1]) - kappa*x[3];
    dxdt[1] = beta*gama*(x[4]*x[1]) - alpha*beta*gama*(x[4]*x[0]) + kappa*x[2];
    dxdt[2] = beta*gama*(x[5]*x[2]) + alpha*beta*gama*(x[5]*x[3]) - kappa*x[1] + omega*x[3];
    dxdt[3] = beta*gama*(x[5]*x[3]) - alpha*beta*gama*(x[5]*x[2]) + kappa*x[0] - omega*x[2];
    dxdt[4] = lambda - x[4] - 1 - (x[0])*(x[0]) - (x[1])*(x[1]) - beta*(x[4])*((x[0])*(x[0])+(x[1])*(x[1]));
    dxdt[5] = lambda - x[5] - 1 - (x[2])*(x[2]) - (x[3])*(x[3]) - beta*(x[5])*((x[2])*(x[2])+(x[3])*(x[3]));



    return dxdt;
}

//IVP of the form du/dt = f(t,u) & u(t0) = u0
//User supplies the current values of t, u, step-size dt, and a function to evaluate the derivative, the function can compute the 4th-order Runge-Kutta estimate to the solution at time t+dt
//t0; current time, m; dimension of space, u0[]; solution estimate at current time, dt: time-step, *f; function which evaluates the derivative of the rhs of problem
//Output; 4th-order Runge-Kutta solution estimate at time t0+dt

double *rk4vec(double t0, int m, double x0[], double dt, double *f(double t, int m, double x[]))
{
    double *k1;
    double *k2;
    double *k3;
    double *k4;
    double t;
    double *x1;
    double *x2;
    double *x3;
    int i;
    double *x;


    //four sample values of the derivative

    k1 = f(t0, m, x0);

    t = t0 + dt/2.0;
    x1 = new double[m];

    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        x1[i] = x0[i] + dt*(k1[i]/2.0);
    }
    k2 = f(t, m, x1);

    x2 = new double[m];

    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        x2[i] = x0[i] + dt*(k2[i]/2.0);
    }
    k3 = f(t, m, x2);

    x3 = new double[m];
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        x3[i] = x0[i] + dt*k3[i];
    }
    k4 = f(t0 + dt, m, x3);

    //combine to estimate solution

    x = new double[m];
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        x[i] = x0[i] + dt*(k1[i] + 2.0*(k2[i]) + 2.0*(k3[i]) + k4[i])/(6.0);
    }

    //free memory

    delete [] k1;
    delete [] k2;
    delete [] k3;
    delete [] k4;
    delete [] x1;
    delete [] x2;
    delete [] x3;

    return x;
}
```

Comment: "has memory issues" should be "leaks like a sieve". Use `std::vector`.

Comment: He doesn't really need this kind of flexibility as it is using only vector 6-dimensional. 6 and only 6. I think that a class/struct with proper constructor, copy constructor, should do the job. The code can be changed in order to use local variables and return by copy of the created struct instead of dynamic allocation. No dynamic allocation is required here.

Comment: I'm not an expert of the problem, but maybe a struct can help in naming the 6 directions (the 6 members of the new struct) with something congruous with the problem they are trying to solve instead of x[0]...x[5]

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance, cause I think the code can be better written, using some struct of 6 doubles instead of dynamic allocations, protecting the access, using copy operator, I think your problem is around dynamic allocation.

I see that some inner loop is called around 10 milions time (see the order of o (2K) and n (5K). The function `r4kvec` return a pointer to a dynamic allocated area that is never released (none of the calls does). Hence 10MLN * 6 * 64bit let me think that you may be very close to exaust the memory (but that depends also on the system you are running it).

So said that:

- `delete[]` the data returned by every single `r4kvec` call.
- as the `new` are in general more expensive than a copy of 6 double, think about having a well designed structure of 6 double in order to use the stack and reduce the complexity.

Hope this may help,
Stefano

---

So a loop like that:

```
    for(j=0; j<n-1000; j++)
        {
            current = ((x[0])*(x[0])+(x[1])*(x[1]));
            xnew = rk4vec(t, m, x, dt, CoupledLaser_rhs);
            for(i=0; i<m; i++)
            {
                x[i] = xnew[i];
            }
            t=t+dt;
        }
```

should become:

```
    for(j=0; j<n-1000; j++)
        {
            current = ((x[0])*(x[0])+(x[1])*(x[1]));
            xnew = rk4vec(t, m, x, dt, CoupledLaser_rhs);
            for(i=0; i<m; i++)
            {
                x[i] = xnew[i];
            }
            t=t+dt;
            delete[] xnew; //release it!
        }
```